# Connect-PnPOnline stopped working

Tags: powershell, pnp, connection

we have a powershell script wich suddenly stopped working.

The first get method after logging in:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -ClientId $AppId -ClientSecret $AppSecret -verbose
```

started to throw error:

```
PS C:\Users\Balint.Rozsa> C:\Temp\Test.ps1
VERBOSE: PnP PowerShell Cmdlets (1.7.0.0)
Get-PnPListItem : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
At C:\Temp\Test.ps1:20 char:10
+ $items = Get-PnPListItem -List "Settings"
+          ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPListItem], TargetInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.GetListItem
```

It seems like the Appid and Appsecret are invalid, but it is not true,
because the script runs without any errors on other machines with the same connection parameters and same version on PnP.Powershell.

Another interesting thing is that logging in with flag -Interactive is working well, but it is not usable in scheduled scripts.

Any ideas how to get the script working on the original machine (behind firewall)?

Get-PnpException returns:

```
Message          : Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
Stacktrace       :    at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
                      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments)
                      at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
                      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass10_0.<Clone>b__0(Object oSender, WebRequestEventArgs webRequestEventArgs)
                      at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
                      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.OnExecutingWebRequest(WebRequestEventArgs args)
                      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.GetWebRequestExecutor()
                      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.<GetFormDigestInfoPrivateAsync>d__37.MoveNext()
                   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.<EnsureFormDigestAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
                   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.<ExecuteQueryAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
                   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.<ExecuteQueryImplementation>d__6.MoveNext()
                   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
                      at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
                      at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
                      at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContextExtensions.ExecuteQueryRetry(ClientRuntimeContext clientContext, Int32 retryCount, String userAgent)
                      at PnP.PowerShell.Commands.PnPWebRetrievalsCmdlet`1.GetWeb()
                      at PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.GetList.ExecuteCmdlet()
                      at PnP.PowerShell.Commands.PnPSharePointCmdlet.ProcessRecord()
ScriptLineNumber : 26
```

Comment: try this: wrap the code in a try/catch, catch the typed exception and look for the InnerException property.  I think the exception you received is a wrapper.

Comment: try catch does not give more info, but i have added the result of Get-PnPException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the proxy.

We got the evidence with testing script:

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $url -ClientId $AppId -ClientSecret $AppSecret -verbose
$ctx = Get-PnPContext
$web = $ctx.Web
$ctx.Load($web)
$ctx.ExecuteQuery()
```

wich returned the whole error page in html, where we found the error message from the proxy server.

Answer (score 1):

On new tenants, [ACS app-only is disabled by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azureacs). You may want to check that it's enabled if you're using a new tenant.

I would consider using [Azure AD App-Only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread) permissions to access SharePoint Online instead of ACS app-only. Microsoft recommend using the Azure AD app-only model because it's modern and more secure.

Comment: Thanks for advice, we will try it. But actually the script is working on other machines.
It must be something with the firewall or proxy settings.